# Performance loss through obfuscation?

Tags: performance, obfuscation

I’ve read that good obfuscation techniques not merely do things like replacing method names with something obscure, but also, for instance, replace strings in the source code with byte arrays and add methods to convert those back to the original strings.

This might be one of those questions leading to opinion-based answers, but I’m going to ask it anyway: Is there any general notion how much performance loss an application would suffer from in case such an obfuscation method is applied? I’ve got in mind a software that is heavily leaning on a database, i.e., queries exist in the code, for instance, as C# `string`s or `StringBuilder` entities.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the downvote. May I cite [Privileges - vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)? It says “Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.” I don’t necessarily object the downvote per se, but at least tell me what’s wrong. For all I can tell, you may well have downvoted merely because I wrote C# and not Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, string obfuscation has a significant performance impact, at the micro-level. With obfuscation, instead of a direct memory lookup you have code that has to execute (every time), and it is usually somewhat complicated, so it is necessarily much worse at the micro-performance level.

However, that cost usually doesn't matter; the time required for the database call (or showing the UI dialog, or sending the error to a log, or network traffic, or ...) is going to be orders of magnitude higher than the cost of converting the string. In most cases, the cost of the conversion is essentially invisible.

As with everything, careful testing is wise, but usually the costs are only "visible" if you are accessing obfuscated strings in a tight loop that is already CPU-performance-sensitive.

Comment: Indeed. Though obfuscation may incur a significant cost in adding complexity to the logic and hindering debugging, effectively leaving less developer time for optimization and making such work more difficult.

Comment: @doynax My understanding was that obfuscation, at least in its automatic incarnation, would be something that I’d add in the compilation loop only after I’m done with the software and have it ready for publication. If I understand you correctly, obfuscation would affect my algorithmic logic in a way that would void previous efforts in optimizing the code. Is this really the case?

Comment: @Informagic: Alas most of us are called upon to debug application errors and analyze usage after publication, at which time you may end up spending time disentangling obfuscated code. For much the same reason as you may end up debugging release builds. And of curse there other commonly employed schemes beyond static code translation, for instance datasets and communication channels are frequently encrypted. At the end of the day studying real code and data flows is one of the most effective strategies for discovering optimization opportunities, so rendering this more difficult is problematic.

Comment: @doynax Ah, good point. I guess that’s the real point where one has to consider the cost trade-off between security and maintainability.

Comment: There are "Optimizing Obfuscators", such as eazfuscator.net.